# how to change innodb_data_file_path on mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am unable to change the value from (ibdata1:10M:autoextend ) to (innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:1000M:autoextend) on MySQL server.

Error Log :

```
150501  7:16:00 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: auto-extending data file ./ibdata1 is of a different size
InnoDB: 1152 pages (rounded down to MB) than specified in the .cnf file:
InnoDB: initial 64000 pages, max 0 (relevant if non-zero) pages!
150501  7:16:00 InnoDB: Could not open or create data files.
150501  7:16:00 InnoDB: If you tried to add new data files, and it failed here,
150501  7:16:00 InnoDB: you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back
150501  7:16:00 InnoDB: to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created
150501  7:16:00 InnoDB: in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of
150501  7:16:00 InnoDB: zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not
150501  7:16:00 InnoDB: remove old data files which contain your precious data!
150501  7:16:00 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
150501  7:16:00 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
150501  7:16:00 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
150501  7:16:00 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Using Mysql version is 5.5.42.